# imports issues in vscode (Python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import

I'm trying to write a python library with the following structre on vsc. When I run tests I got an error no module named pytrader. pytrader is a python package it has an **init** on it. In pycharm i used to set the src folder as the source directory and everything works. Any help thank you
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLxhA.png)

Comment: How are you running the tests?

Comment: I run the following command pytest test/:  here is what i what on my terminal (.venvTrading) PS C:\Users\abdel\Desktop\trading-pytrader> pytest tests/

Comment: I see in VS Code you are using PowerShell. Can you switch to a command prompt in VS Code and try that instead? In VS Code you can click the drop down next to the plus sign in the terminal area and select Command Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The action of `set the src folder as the source directory` in the PyCharm is to add the `src folder` path to the **PYTHONPATH**.

In the VSCode, it has no way to add it directly, but it's possible to edit it when you debugging, you can add this in the launch.json file:

```
"env": {"PYTHONPATH":"${workspaceRoot}/src"},
```

And you can add it directly in the python file like this:

```
sys.path.append("D:\\TestPlace")
```